# Getting error saying : [ts] Can not find name 'firebase'

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an angular app connected to a firebase database. I am able to read data from the database..
however I am trying to enable log in and sign up feature to the app.. But when I try to do

firebase.auth();

I get an error saying [ts] Can not find name 'firebase'

I am trying to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU)

Am I missing some imports at the top?  Currently I have just these...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database'
```

My code inside app.component.ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  courses:any[];


  constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase)
  {
    db.list('/courses').valueChanges().subscribe(courses=>{
      this.courses = courses;
      console.log(this.courses);
    })


    const auth = firebase.auth(); // -->> ERROR

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That video is pretty old so there have been some changes. You could downgrade to a version from around the time the video was release. Or you could use the "new" way. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) is an example on authentication. Also, [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) is the entire changelog.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the "new" way and it works for me. :)